# How to remove an item after a filter from query set?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Currently, I have results from a queryset filter.

```
 Results = Model.objects.filter(conditional=satified..etc.)
```

How do you remove individual results form Results. I thought Results was a list and tried .remove(item) but it doesn't seem to work.  Is there another way to remove individual items?

Answer (score 4):

use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) again or [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) method on your queryset. **E.g** :

```
results = Model.objects.filter(conditional=satified)
results  = results.exclude(param=your_param)
# or
results  = results.filter(param=your_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

the result of `Model.objects.filter` is a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) class,not a `list`.

And `filter` just take some models from database to memory,once done,any operation to the result is operating on data in memory,not database,so data in database won't change.So if you want to delete some models from database,you can find the specific models from your result of `filter` and call its `delete` method,then the model will be removed from database.

Comment: I just want to remove one of the results from the filter, not the whole model.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use `exclude` to exclude models you don't want.refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) and search `exclude`.